# Idiomatically capturing "all idempotent semirings induce a partial order"

Tags: typeclass, isabelle

I am trying to capture the fact that there's an induced partial ordering in any idempotent semiring in Isabelle/HOL but am having trouble working out the best/correct way to do it.

I define:

```
class idem_semiring_1 = semiring_1 +
  assumes idem [algebra_simps]: ‹a + a = a›
begin

definition less_eq :: ‹'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool›
  where ‹less_eq a b ⟷ a + b = b›

definition less :: ‹'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool›
  where ‹less a b ⟷ less_eq a b ∧ ¬ less_eq b a›

end
```

Now, it's straightforward to demonstrate that `less_eq` and `less` satisfy all of the laws of the `order` type class.  However, is there a way of convincing Isabelle/HOL that any instance of `idem_semiring_1` is also necessarily an instance of `order` using these definitions, so that the following query type-checks?

```
term ‹(y::'a::{idem_semiring_1}) ≤ x›
```

No combination of subclass, sublocale, etc., incantations seems to achieve what I want.  In particular, the following:

```
sublocale idem_semiring_1 ⊆ order less_eq less
  by (standard; clarsimp simp add: algebra_simps less_eq_def less_def) (metis add.assoc)
```

seems to work, as in the following lemmas become trivially provable via `simp`:

```
lemma
  fixes x::‹'a::{idem_semiring_1}›
  shows ‹less_eq x x›
    by simp

lemma
  assumes ‹less_eq x y›
      and ‹less_eq y z›
    shows ‹less_eq x z›
  using assms by simp
```

but the following does not type-check:

```
lemma
  fixes x :: ‹'a::{idem_semiring_1}›
  shows ‹x ≤ x›
```

What am I not doing to convince Isabelle to connect the `≤` syntax with the `less_eq` definition?

Answer (score 1):

What if you defined idem_semiring_1 like this:

```
class idem_semiring_1 = semiring_1 + order +
  assumes idem [algebra_simps]: ‹a + a = a› and
      less_eq_idem_semiring_1: ‹a ≤ b ⟷ a + b = b›
```

Comment: Thanks. I had considered this (it's the approach taken by Kleene_Algebra in the AFP, I think) and should have mentioned this in my question.  The disadvantage of this approach is that it requires anybody instantiating the typeclass to provide the definitions of `less_eq` and `less`, along with all of the proofs that they satisfy the partial-order laws, at every point of instantiation.  Not a major annoyance, but the canonical ordering is something that "falls out" of the definition of an idempotent semiring for free and I was really wondering whether this can be captured in Isabelle/HOL.

Comment: If it falls out shouldn't you be able to prove it inside of `class idem_semiring_1 = semiring_1 + order + assumes idem [algebra_simps]: ‹a + a = a› begin ... end`?

If I state `lemma less_eq_idem_semiring_1: ‹a ≤ b ⟷ a + b = b›` inside of it `nitpick` finds a counterexample. You maybe need to add more type classes to idem_semiring_1.

Comment: I'm trying to show that given an arbitrary idempotent semiring I can produce a partial order on the same carrier set where the ordering relation is defined by `a + b = b`, i.e. there's a generic construction taking an idempotent semiring as input and producing a partial order.  That this leads to a partial order is easily shown (indeed, the `sublocale` command in my question shows this, unless mistaken).  You are trying to show given an idempotent semiring with an order on the carrier the ordering relation must coincide with `a + b = b`.  This is a different property, no?

Comment: I think it's essentially the same in an Isabelle/HOL context but we probably need someone with more math and Isabelle knowledge to chime in.